# Julia 1.6: can't git clone using proxy (but git alone can) on Windows

Tags: git, proxy, julia

I tried to use proxy configuration for faster connection on my `git`, my config was `git config --global http.proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080`, and it works fine with `git`. However, after applying this, my Julia package installation fails as following:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> add IJulia
Installing known registries into `C:\Users\kyu\.julia`
Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:HTTP, invalid URL: 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080')
```

If I unset proxy by `git config --global --unset http.proxy` it goes back to normal.

Moreover, I would like to ask, in this case, I successfully `git clone` the repository using `git`, how can I install this package locally on Julia so I can skip the proxy issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing slash? I.e. `'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/'`. Possibly relevant: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33111#issuecomment-541224149 and https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/5255 .

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. Also to mention, Julia Pkg.add() works fine with proxy on LINUX, but now I am doing it with Windows, doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried many ways but all failed, the only solution is to configure system-wise proxy on Windows.

Start menu => Proxy settings => Use a proxy server => save